# jquery gradient image height

Tags: jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery I am facing a some problem with jQuery gradient image please give me some solution for this

I have one div divided vertically in three part left, middle,right.The div has a background images (that is gradient) .and there is some data in the div. I want that the image height should be increase when the user input more data in the div

Can we increase the height of the gradient image using jQuery. Please give me some reference site or some solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you need JQuery to do this for you; it will be fun to do it on you own.

As you know, you can style the div such that its height will increase as you add more content to it. So your question really is how to make the gradient background appear the way you want it: you might want the gradient to grow lighter and lighter at the bottom, say, as the div increases in height. It just so happens (lucky you!) that background-image CSS is rich and capable. That's why it's fun: it actually works!

Read about CSS background-position for some ideas. You might find that the effect you want is automatic.

-- pete

Comment: I have tried with css but there is an image in the background of the div and with css position it is not posible

Comment: It's certainly true that you can have only one background-image :-) What is the URL of the page in question?